# 過去ログ、ヒストリーを確認したい

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spyder

python　spyder　の過去ログ、ヒストリーを確認したい。前回やったコマンドと結果の記録がない。

Comment: これのことでしょうか? [History](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/historylog.html)

Comment: @kunif さんありがとうございます。そうなんですけど過去のコマンド・結果のヒストリーが出てきません。初歩ですみません。

Comment: こんな記事があるので、その辺のフォルダを探してみては？ [Accessing the spyder history log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60548051/9014308)